# How to filter Range criteria using ElasticSearch Repository

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I need to fetch Employees who joined between 2021-12-01 to 2021-12-31. I am using ElasticsearchRepository to fetch data from ElasticSearch index.
How can we fetch range criteria using repository.

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Employee, String>,EmployeeRepositoryCustom {

    List<Employee> findByJoinedDate(String joinedDate);
}
```

I have tried Between option like below: But it is returning no results

```
List<Employee> findByJoinedDateBetween(String fromJoinedDate, String toJoinedDate);
```

My Index configuration

```
@Document(indexName="employee", createIndex=true,type="_doc", shards = 4)
public class Employee {  
         
    @Field(type=FieldType.Text)
    private String joinedDate;
```

Comment: what data type has the `joinedDate` property in your `Employee` class? This should be type that can be mapped to a date in Elasticsearch

Comment: oh ok. joinedDate is String in Employee class. So i need to change it as Date?

Comment: I have updated question with my index configuration

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** You seem to be using an outdated version of Spring Data Elasticsearch. The `type` parameter of the `@Document`
annotation was deprecated in 4.0 and removed in 4.1, as Elasticsearch itself does not support typed indices since
version 7.

To your question:

In order to be able to have a range query for dates in Elasticsearch the field in question must be of type date (the
Elasticsearch type). For your entity this would mean (I refer to the attributes from the current version 4.3):

```java
    @Nullable
    @Field(type = FieldType.Date, pattern = "uuuu-MM-dd", format = {})
    private LocalDate joinedDate;
```

This defines the `joinedDate` to have a `date` type and sets the string representation to the given `pattern`. The
empty `format` argument makes sure that the additional default values (`DateFormat.date_optional_time` and `DateFormat. epoch_millis`) are not set here. This results in the
following mapping in the index:

```json
{
    "properties": {
        "joinedDate": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "uuuu-MM-dd"
        }
    }
}
```

If you check the mapping in your index (`GET localhost:9200/employee/_mapping`) you will see that in your case the
`joinedDate` is of type text. You will either need to delete the index and have it recreated by your application or
create it with a new name and then, after the application has written the mapping, reindex the data from the old
index into the new one (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/docs-reindex.html).

Once you have the index with the correct mapping in place, you can define the method in your repository like this:

```java
List<Employee> findByJoinedDateBetween(LocalDate fromJoinedDate, LocalDate toJoinedDate);
```

and call it:

```java
repository.findByJoinedDateBetween(LocalDate.of(2021, 1, 1), LocalDate.of(2021, 12, 31));
```

Comment: I have removed the type=_doc and modified joinedDate filed as Date Type. I am getting failed to parse joinedDate field. I have tried with different format. not able to resolve it. Empty format is not required as we need to fix it for both lower and higher version @Document(indexName="employee", createIndex=true, shards = 4)
public class Employee { 

    @Nullable
    @Field(type = FieldType.Date, pattern = "uuuu-MM-dd", format = DateFormat.ordinal_date)
    private LocalDate joinedDate

Comment: Error is : ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=failed to parse field [joinedDate] of type [date] in document with id '3eb32dd8-df02-4dda-b58c-f137fd1fe729'. Preview of field's value: '{dayOfWeek=THURSDAY, month=JANUARY, year=2022, era=CE, dayOfYear=6, dayOfMonth=6, monthValue=1, chronology={calendarType=iso8601, id=ISO}, leapYear=false}']]; nested: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_state_exception, reason=Can't get text on a START_OBJECT at 1:78]]; I have deleted old index and trying this newly created index

Comment: which version of Spring Data Elasticsearch do you use and how to you configure your client (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.rest)? ordinal_date would be _"uuuu-DDD"_ this is different from what you had in the first place. Can you privide a minimal runnable example taht produces this error?

Comment: dependency in my pom.xml:
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
  
In .m2 repository i could see the version is 2.3.9
  .m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch\2.3.9.RELEASE

Comment: public class Employee { 
  
    @Nullable
    @Field(type = FieldType.Date, pattern = "uuuu-MM-dd", format = DateFormat.date)
    private LocalDate joinedDate;
 }
 
ElasticSearch index metadata
"joinedDate": {
"format": "date",
"type": "date"
} I will try to share runnable example

Comment: I am using ElasticsearchRepository<Employee, String> to save data in index

Comment: without pattern parameter, it is storing value as below: joinedDate.year
joinedDate.month
joinedDate.dayOfMonth
joinedDate.dayOfWeek
joinedDate.era
joinedDate.dayOfYear
joinedDate.monthValue
joinedDate.chronology
joinedDate.leapYear

Comment: posted new question for DateFormat https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70723816/how-to-format-and-store-date-in-elasticsearch